# Borders to specified range and sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code to apply borders to all cells in range.

```
Sub Borders()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False    'Prevents screen refreshing
Dim lngLstCol As Long, lngLstRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Dim rngCell As Range, r As Long, c As Long
Dim skp As Boolean

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    lngLstRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    lngLstCol = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    For Each rngCell In ws.Range("A1:A" & lngLstRow)
        If rngCell.Value <> "" Then
            r = rngCell.Row
            c = rngCell.Column

            With ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, c), ws.Cells(r, lngLstCol)).Borders
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous    'Setting style of border line
                .Weight = xlThin    'Setting weight of border line
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic    'Setting colour of border line
            End With
        End If
    Next
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True    'Enables screen refreshing
End Sub
```

How do I use this code to ignore the first sheet and apply borders to only sheets after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply loop through sheets by index, starting at 2.

Note: the user can re-order the sheets, so "the first sheet" may not be the one you expect

This code also accounts for possible sheet types other than Worksheet

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim idx As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    For idx = 2 To wb.Sheets.Count
        If wb.Sheets(idx).Type = xlWorksheet Then
            Set ws = wb.Sheets(idx)
            With ws
                'all your ws code ...
            End With
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

To deal with the possibility that a user moves the sheets, you can use a sheets [code name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-codename-property-excel)

In this code, `SheetX` is the code name of the sheet you don't want to format (adjust it to suit your needs)

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim idx As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    For idx = 1 To wb.Sheets.Count
        If wb.Sheets(idx).Type = xlWorksheet Then
            If Not wb.Sheets(idx) Is SheetX Then
                Set ws = wb.Sheets(idx)
                With ws
                    'all your ws code ...
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I am sorry, I am unable to add my code to the solution you provided. I get errors.

Comment: Then update your Q with what you tried and the error you get

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Sorry for the late response. I was able to debug and run the code successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Borders()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, row As Range

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then      ' replace Sheet1 with the name of the Sheet to skip
            For Each row In ws.UsedRange.Rows
                If row(1) <> "" Then row.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous    
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```